# How to get the max date in Oracle using a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

i have a table named **remit_bill** and i would like to get the max date from this table using the following query but it keeps on showing me errors.there are several dates under the same bill_no.i want to get the maximum date with coll_amt value.any help with this would be appreciated.

```
SQL> desc remit_bill
 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 SC_CD                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
 RMT_NO                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
 RMT_DT                                   DATE
 BILL_NO                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
 COLL_AMT                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
```

Query :

```
select sum(COLL_AMT) FROM REMIT_BILL AS P

WHERE bill_no = '887332' and rmt_dt=(SELECT MAX(rmt_dt) FROM REMIT_BILL AS P2

where P2.bill_no=P.BILL_NO

--GROUP BY COLL_AMT

)

GROUP BY COLL_AMT
```

Error Message :

```
select sum(COLL_AMT) FROM REMIT_BILL AS P
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


SQL>
```

Image:

[image: tab]

Comment: Oracle doesn't support the `AS` keyword for *table* aliases. Just use `FROM REMIT_BILL P`

Comment: This is not entirely true, XMLTABLE and JSON_TABLE can be aliased using 'AS' and in subquery factoring clause is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select sum(p.COLL_AMT) FROM REMIT_BILL P

WHERE p.bill_no = '887332' and p.rmt_dt=(SELECT MAX(rmt_dt) FROM REMIT_BILL P2

where P2.bill_no=P.BILL_NO

)

GROUP BY p.COLL_AMT
```